# QGraphicsSvgItem event propagation (Interactive svg viewer)

Tags: python, svg, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

currently I'm building a minimalistic svg viewer in which the user should be able to select subitems of the drawn graphics.

The piecewise rendering of the svg is achieved by using

QGraphicsSvgItem with a shared renderer. The items are then added one by one to the QGraphicsScene which is assosiated to a QGraphicsView.

No comes the tricky part. I need single selection of the items (by clicking on them) and a multi selection with a rubber band.

Currently I'm struggling with the propagation of the mouse click events. The documentation said that all events are propagated from the children to parents.
I other words: By clicking on an SvgItem I would assume, that the event handler of the Item is triggered **before** the handler of the viewer. This is not the case.

I've created an example application:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QGraphicsSvgItem, QSvgRenderer


class SvgItem(QGraphicsSvgItem):
    def __init__(self, id, renderer, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.id = id
        self.setSharedRenderer(renderer)
        self.setElementId(id)
        bounds = renderer.boundsOnElement(id)
        self.setPos(bounds.topLeft())
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: 'QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent'):
        print('svg item: ' + self.id + ' - mousePressEvent()')
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: 'QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent'):
        print('svg item: ' + self.id + ' - mouseReleaseEvent()')
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)


class SvgViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._renderer = QSvgRenderer()
        self.setScene(self._scene)

    def set_svg(self, data):
        self.resetTransform()
        self._scene.clear()
        self._renderer.load(data)

        item1 = SvgItem('p2', self._renderer)
        self._scene.addItem(item1)

        item2 = SvgItem('p3', self._renderer)
        self._scene.addItem(item2)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: 'QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent'):
        print('SvgViewer - mousePressEvent()')
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: 'QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent'):
        print('SvgViewer - mouseReleaseEvent()')
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.viewer = SvgViewer(self)
        vb_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vb_layout.addWidget(self.viewer)

        img = b'''
                <svg viewBox='0 0 108 95' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
                    <g transform='scale(0.1)'>
                        <path id="p2" d='M249,699v43h211v-43h-64l-2,3l-2,4l-4,3c0,0-1,2-2,2h-4c-2,0-3,0-4,1c-1,1-3,1-3,
                            2l-3,4c0,1-1,2-2,2h-4c0,0-2,1-3,0l-3-1c-1,0-3-1-3-2c-1-1,0-2-1-3l-1-3c-1-1-2-1-3-1c-1,0-4,
                            0-4-1c0-2,0-3-1-4v-3v-3z'/>
                        <path id="p3" d='M385,593c0,9-6,15-13,15c-7,0-13-6-13-15c0-8,12-39,14-39c1,0,12,31,12,39'/>
                    </g>
                </svg>'''
        self.viewer.set_svg(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 600, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Clicking on the displayed svg item yields the following console output:

```
SvgViewer - mousePressEvent()
svg item: p3 - mousePressEvent()
SvgViewer - mouseReleaseEvent()
svg item: p3 - mouseReleaseEvent()
```

My goal is the following behaviour:

1. the user clicks on an item -> this item is selected (the event is accepted and a selection rectangle is not created)
2. the users clicks on a blank area and starts to move the mouse -> a selection rectangle starts to show up

How can I skip the event handling in the viewer when the left mouse click is above an visible item (preferential without any logic based on manual positions checks)?

Any suggest is more than welcome!

Comment: Could you explain me better, what do you want to not happen when you click left on a visible item? On the other hand the items are not widgets so the logic is different so it would be great if you signal the documentation that you indicate that the mouse events spread from parents to children in the QGraphicsItem

Comment: what is the meaning of *selection rectangle is not created*?